# Exception in WCF client

Tags: c#, for-loop

I am using WCf service in my windowsApplication... I got the exception in my client When i am trying to add items in Listbox by using ForEach Loop... The exception is "Collection was modified enumuration may not execute".
How shall i solve this exception....

And my code is,

```
            foreach (ClsPC pc in iclsobj.GetPC())
            {
            if (listBox1.Items.Count == 0)
            {
            listBox1.Items.Add(pc.IPAddress);
             }
            else
            {
            for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
            if (!listBox1.Items[i].ToString().Contains(pc.IPAddress))
            {
            listBox1.Items.Add(pc.IPAddress);
             }
          }
        }
       }
 client.Close();
```

client = null;

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to modify the collection in you list box while looping through it (the inner loop), which isn't really such a hot idea.  You'd be better performing this in your data select (i.e. a get distinct PC), or limiting the returned list, possibly something like:

```
var pcs = iclsobj.GetPC().Select(pc => new { IPAddress = pc.IPAddress}).Distinct();
```

And then just binding your listbox to this.

Comment: Thanks for Your Code....i tried your code but i got different line...
 
(ie)System.Linq.Enumerable+<DistinctIterator>d__7a`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.String]]

now how can i get that IPAddress

Comment: I can't make a whole lot of sense of the text in your first comment, but as for the second, it's as simple as how you add any enumerable to a collection.  Personally, I'd set your filtered list as the datasource and then call databind...

Comment: Book might not be a bad idea at this stage...
lstBox1.DataSource = pcs;
lstBox1.DataBind();

Comment: i cannt get lstbox1.Databinding() option... lstbox1 does not contain DataBinding function...

Comment: i used windowsforms so that i couldnt get Databind() function... Now tell me one thing that i have to get the IPlist as List<> instead of Var... what shall i do for this?

Comment: In your code i got some value in pcs Which i mentioned first post.. In that line containing the ipaddress list in resultview option.. Now how shall i get that result view.... Tell me..

Comment: It should be an enumerable list - you can use code similar to what you first posted - loop through it (foreach (var ipAddress in pcs) {...}) and add it to your list that way.

Comment: Thans for nice code.... I used (var ipaddress in pcs) line i got the ipaddress but it comes as repeatly when i click the buttton...